# Multiple domains on one server and multiple url rewrite rules htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, multiple-domains

I have two wordpress sites lying on the same hosting account, they are each in their own subdirectory and have their own database.

-Root

--site1

--site2

Site 1 has 3 domain names 
site1.dk 
site1.eu 
site1.org

Site 2 has 1 domainame 
site2.com

I would like to point site1.dk, site1.eu, site1.org into the subfolder site1. And site2.com down in the subdirectory site2.

In addition, I want to remove the subfolder name site1 / 2

I have solved site1 with the following htaccess in the root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site1/(.*)$ http://www.site1.dk/site1$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1 \.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site1/(.*)$ http://www.site1.dk/site1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site1/(.*)$ http://www.site1.dk/site1$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site1/(.*)$ http://www.site1.dk/site1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site1/(.*)$ http://www.site1.dk/site1$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site1/(.*)$ http://www.site1.dk/site1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ site1/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site1/$1
```

All the above urls goes in to site1 subfolder and the url look like this site1.dk. Done and ok!

But if i add this to the root htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site2/(.*)$ http://www.site2.dk/site1$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site2\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site2/(.*)$ http://www.site2.dk/site2/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ site2/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site2/$1
```

Everything falls apart.

I'm not so familiar with htaccess and url rewriting and could use some help.

Thanks in advance

/ / Kasper

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you'd want to do this with a [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/index.html), not through `.htaccess`. Depending on how your server is set up, you may need to edit `apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` directly or work through an abstraction layer in cPanel/Plesk/WHM or something similar.

You shouldn't need an `.htaccess` file in your root folder in the example above. If your hosts are set up properly, this shouldn't be accessible to a visitor from the web.

Comment: Unfortunately, the server is not set up virtual host, otherwise it was a good solution you came with! 

Is it not possible to do with htaccess?